# how to get a sql statement from a table into an active query

Tags: sql-server

I´d like to know if there´s a way to get sql queries I stored in a table into an active sql query.
Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM <SELECT query FROM table n WHERE id = 1>
```

This returns a table with a single col and row with the desired query written inside the table, but I am not able to execute that query inside the first SELECT statement.

Any input apreciated.

Comment: Look at the [EXEC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) or [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Comment: what version of Sql Server do you have

Comment: At home I´m using MS SQL Server 2014, at the office I´m using 2012, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to run the query stored in the table straight from the query try adding the row to a variable and then run sp_executesql. This works only if there is just 1 record with an ID of 1

```
Declare @sqlQuery nvarchar(max);
select @sqlQuery = query from table where ID = 1;

exec sp_executesql @sqlQuery
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d076b/9)

Comment: @JFinster Do me a solid and click the check mark next to my answer. Glad that worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you mean I think

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Id IN (SELECT id FROM table n WHERE id = 1)
```